# Particle.js won't load

Tags: javascript, particles, particles.js

I want use Particles Js in a website, but the plugin isn't loaded.

This is my HTML

```
<div class="metodologia__imagem">
 <img src="dist/img/metodologia_Humans.png" alt="Metodologia aplicadas">
    <div class="atomo">
        <div id="particles-js"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the JS, I put the code the website give to me in the particles file, but I have the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined
```

The caller is:

```
$('#particles-js').particlesJS.load(function() {
    console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
  });
```

I try use the original code, but won't work too

```
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function() {
  console.log('particles.js loaded - callback');
});
```

I don't know where is the error or who to corret.

**IMPORTANT -** I use gulp to minify all my CSS and JS.

Comment: After a page load, are you able to invoke the `particleJS` function from console?

Comment: Also try it without gulp first so you and we can be sure minification is or is not the problem.

Comment: 1) `console.log(particleJs)` what do you get? 
2) how are you using particleJs? through cdn? global scope variable then?

Comment: After the page load I can't invoke the `particleJS` from the console.

Comment: I am using the plugin as a script page, and in the app.js the caller. If i use the `console.log(particleJS)` i get the following message `Uncaught ReferenceError: particleJs is not defined`